# textarea affecting other tds

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this simple `form`:

[image]

Then here where the problem occurs:

[image]

Notice that the `<td>` that includes *new message, inbox, and set* `buttons` changes when I resized the `textarea`. So how can I fix this thank you.

**edit** here is the code (sorry):

```
<table style="border: 3px solid red; margin-left: 0px; width:43%; " align="left">
    <td style="border: 3px solid gray; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 50px;">
        <form method="post" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
            <input type="submit" name="create" value="New&nbsp;Message" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        </form>
    </td>
    <td style="border: 3px solid gray; padding: 0px;  margin: 0; width: 50px;">
        <form method="post" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
            <input type="submit" name="inbox" value="Inbox" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        </form>
    </td>
    <td style="border: 3px solid gray; padding: 0px;  margin: 0; width: 50px;">
        <form method="post" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
            <input type="submit" name="sent" value="Sent" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        </form>
    </td>
    <td style="border: 3px solid dimgray; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 100%;">

    </td>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 3px solid blue; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: <?php echo escape($create_d); ?>" colspan="4">
        <form method="post" style="padding: 0px;">
            <label for="message">Create Msg</label><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
            <label for="to">To:</label>
            <input type="text" id="to" name="to" placeholder="IGN"><br>
            <textarea id="message" name="msg" maxlength="1000"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="create" value="Send">
        </form>
    </td>

    <td style="border: 3px solid red; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: <?php echo escape($inbox_d); ?>" colspan="4">
        <?php echo $inbox_tbl; ?>
    </td>
    <td style="border: 3px solid green; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: <?php echo escape($sent_d); ?>" colspan="4">
        <?php echo $sent_tbl;?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Where is the starting point in code? Please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added the code that the `form` I represented, just ignore some, styles there because the `form` is only a bit part of the whole page. thank you

Comment: why you want table? you can use div  with bootstrap for responsive design.

Comment: You want the textarea to not to resize? if so, use `resize: none` css property.

Comment: @NitinDhomse I am not using javascript

Comment: @Mr_Green, I can't do that because I want to change the size of the `textarea` when I style it. That said size will be the default of the `textarea`.

Comment: @phew keep the header part in different table.

Comment: @Mr_Green,  thank you, that is what is on my mind. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/c28t27x2/

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<table style="border: 3px solid red; margin-left: 0px; width:43%; " align="left">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 3px solid gray; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 50px;">
        <form method="post" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
            <input type="submit" name="create" value="New&nbsp;Message" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        </form>
    </td>
    <td style="border: 3px solid gray; padding: 0px;  margin: 0; width: 50px;">
        <form method="post" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
            <input type="submit" name="inbox" value="Inbox" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        </form>
    </td>
    <td style="border: 3px solid gray; padding: 0px;  margin: 0; width: 50px;">
        <form method="post" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
            <input type="submit" name="sent" value="Sent" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        </form>
    </td>
    <td style="border: 3px solid dimgray; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 100%;">

    </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table style="border: 3px solid red; margin-left: 0px; width:43%; " align="left">

    <tbody>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 3px solid blue; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: <?php echo escape($create_d); ?>" colspan="4">
        <form method="post" style="padding: 0px;">
            <label for="message">Create Msg</label><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
            <label for="to">To:</label>
            <input type="text" id="to" name="to" placeholder="IGN"><br>
            <textarea id="message" name="msg" maxlength="1000"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="create" value="Send">
        </form>
    </td>

    <td style="border: 3px solid red; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: <?php echo escape($inbox_d); ?>" colspan="4">
        <?php echo $inbox_tbl; ?>
    </td>
    <td style="border: 3px solid green; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: <?php echo escape($sent_d); ?>" colspan="4">
        <?php echo $sent_tbl;?>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```